# Who is accountable for underage drinking when the alcohol is easily accessed by the public? (United Kingdom)

Tags: criminal-law, united-kingdom, alcohol

I live in the UK. A group of teenagers are able to access large quantities of alcohol from an unsecured area (out in the open) at the rear of a small shopping complex.

Are there any UK regulations that the off-licence or the owner of the shopping complex are in breach of? At the very least, is the off-licence being seriously neglectful?

I've reported the incidents to the police and council. I was told abruptly by the off-licence that they wouldn't do anything to prevent this from occurring in the future.

Are any laws being broken by anyone besides the youths? Are there any other official bodies that I should report this to?

Comment: By *access* you mean steal? Or is it left out, say for the rubbish collectors?

Comment: @TimLymington it's not deliberately being left out for just anyone to take.  They're technically trespassing to get to the crates.  But the area is completely open for them to do so